# xss_clean in Codeigniter 2 work fine but in Codeigniter 4 doesn't?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-4

I'm trying to migrate a system in codeigniter 2 to version 4 of the same framework, but when I want to execute the function `$nomUsr = $ security-> xss_clean ($ this-> input-> post ('nomUsr'));` in CI4 this returns an error. I'm forgetting to load something into another file or xss_clean is just no longer used in codeigniter 4?
Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `xss_clean` function for CI4 because that is the wrong way to prevent XSS. here is the [official reply](https://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-75338-post-371313.html#pid371313)

> XSS_clean should be conspired deprecated. That's a not a recommended
> practice to rely on. **You should filter your inputs AND escape your
> outputs.**
>
> Input:
> https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/libraries/validation.html
> https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/incoming/incomingrequest.html#retrieving-input
> **"Filtering Input Data"**
>
> Output:
> https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/outgoing/view_renderer.html#escaping-data
> https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/outgoing/view_renderer.html#escaping-contexts